# Has the US National Guard ever been deployed nationwide before, as has been done with the Covid-19 pandemic?

Tags: united-states, military, disasters

I've tried looking in various places online and have been unable to find when in US history we have had nationwide deployments of the National Guards? Where can I find this out? Or do you know?

**Edit**: As per comments, I want to clarify **a)** trying to find when the N. G. was deployed **to** every state **b)** I've browsed through the first 5 pages of Google results for "nationwide deployments of US National Guards" as well as browsed some Wikipedia articles, which articles specifically I no longer remember.

Comment: Hi Serj Sagan and welcome to History SE. Please tell us where you have looked so that folks here don't waste time looking in places you've already checked out. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on how you phrase the details, it is unlikely to have ever happened. Until 2006, National Guard units were under the control of State Governors.  A nationwide deployment would have required coordinated activity by all the state Governors. A brief review of the relevant [Wikipedia:National Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_National_Guard) page indicates no such event.

Comment: This **may** have happened during Hurricane Katrina, when the National Guard was mobilised via the web of [Emergency Management Assistance Compacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_Management_Assistance_Compact). nationalguard.mil states that: "Army and Air Guard members from **every** state, territory, and the District of Columbia gave assistance to Gulf Coast states". However, the Wikipedia article says "65,000 personnel from **48 states**, the District of Columbia, Puerto Rico, and the U.S. Virgin Islands were deployed under EMAC . . . in response to Hurricanes Katrina and Rita".

Comment: The last truly national scale disaster internal to the US was the 1918 flu pandemic.  With Katrina, I think the question is whether the OP means that the National Guard was deployed *from* all states or *to* all states.